# How to sort a list by key with None type elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list where some elements are None type. I need to sort this list, but I receive this error because None evidently can't be sorted.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
    random.sort(key=takeSecond)
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

This is an example program:

```
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# random list
random = [(2, None), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]

# sort list with key
random.sort(key=takeSecond)

# print list
print('Sorted list:', random)
```

How can I solve this issue sorting the other elements and maybe put `None` types at the end of the list?

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers, and if the list contains strings instead of int?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to change your question after it's been answered (because now it's a different question). Regardless, can't you figure-out to apply the answers you already have to handle the slightly different scenario?

Comment: I can apply the answers, but in this particular case I don't know what string value it's appropriate to get the same result of float('inf')  or sys.maxsize. I can think "zzzzzzzzz", but it doesn't look very elegant. If you know an answer, you can help me.

Comment: I have an idea that might work — but as I said previously, you're now asking a different question than you originally did (which is unfair to the folks who have already answered).

Comment: Ok, I'll do another question.

Comment: OK, I have an answer ready to post.

Comment: Thanks I'll see you tomorrow then, now I can't wait 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your key function:

```py
import math

def takeSecond(elem):
  return elem[1] if elem[1] is not None else math.inf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manage the case of None by assigning a high value to it, e.g, `float('inf')`.

```
>>> lst = [(2, None), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]
>>> lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[1] if x[1] is not None else float('inf'))
>>> lst
[(4, 1), (1, 3), (3, 4), (2, None)]
```